# Aggregate mongoDB text search scores on self-referenced documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here is a problem I am stuck with. I need to perform a text search over a hierarchy of documents set as follow:

```
// simplified mongoose schema definitions
const opp = new Schema({
  activity: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Activity' },
  team: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Team' },
  contribs: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Contribution' }]
});

const activitySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: 'String', required: true },
  language: { type: 'String', required: true, default: 'en' },
  location: { type: 'String', required: true },
  org: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Org' },
  description: { type: 'String', required: true },
  translation: [translationSchema]
});

const orgSchema = new Schema({
 name: { type: 'String', required: true },
 language: { type: 'String', required: true, default: 'en' },
 description: { type: 'String', required: true },
 translation: [translationSchema]
});
```

From this, I wish to perform a full-text search to retrieve all opportunities where the search terms appear in:

- name, location, or description of the activities,
- or in the underlying organizer's name or description
- or in one of these documents translation.

So first, I created the text indexes for mongo to perform the full-text searches :

```
// schema indexes
orgSchema.index({ name: 'text', description: 'text', 'translation.name': 'text', 'translation.description': 'text' }, { name: 'fulltext-search' });
activitySchema.index({ name: 'text', location: 'text', description: 'text', 'translation.name': 'text', 'translation.location': 'text', 'translation.description': 'text' }, { name: 'fulltext-search' });
```

And here comes the troubles...
Mongo's aggregation cannot be performed on referenced documents, so I have to aggregate results of text searches independently per collection.

```
// Search text on Orgs
const scoredOrgs = await Org.aggregate(
  { $match: { $text: { $search: searchTerms } } },
  { $project: { _id: 1, score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } })
.exec()
.then(scores => {
  const scoreMap = {};
  scores.forEach(s => { scoreMap[s._id] = s.score; });
  return scoreMap;
});

// return example
[ 
 { '58bd295f2464490015b8ae31': 0.9119718309859155 },
 { '58bd85a42464490015b8ae9e': 1.8068181818181817 }
]

// Search text on Activities
const scoredActivities = await Activity.aggregate(
  { $match: 
    { $or: [
      { $text: { $search: searchTerms } }, 
      { org: { $in: Object.keys(scoredOrgs).map(ObjectId) } }
    ]}
  },
  { $project: { _id: 1, org: 1, score: { $meta: 'textScore' }}})
.exec()
.then(scores => {
  const scoreMap = {};
  scores.forEach(s => { scoreMap[s._id] = s.score + (scoredOrgs[s.org] || 0); });
  return scoreMap;
});

//return example
{ 
  '58bd50912464490015b8ae43': 1.5369718309859155,
  '58bd86ae2464490015b8aea0': 2.4068181818181817,
  '58bd4f642464490015b8ae3f': 0.6,
  '58bd2a3c2464490015b8ae33': 0.9119718309859155,
  '58bd2b0e2464490015b8ae35': 0.9119718309859155
}
```

I admit that this becomes messy, but at this point I have an unsorted Array with the activity Id and the sum of scores of its fields and its underlying document (Org) fields search.

In the end, I will be able to find and sort the 'Opportunities' documents as a subset from the matching Activity Ids, and sort them afterward according to the calculated scores.

```
// Final Opps aggregation sorting and population
const opps = await Opportunity.find({
  team: ObjectId('58bd76792464490015b8ae74'),
  activity: { $in: Object.keys(scoredActivities).map(ObjectId) }
 })
.populate('team')
.deepPopulate('activity.org')
.exec()
.then(opps => {
  opps.map(opp => Object.assign(opp, { score: scoredActivities[opp.activity._id] }));
  return opps.sort((x,y) => x.score < y.score);
});
```

I see that this is inefficient, as it requires several separate aggregations. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Do I need to manipulate the data out of the aggregation framework or can this be done within the pipelines?

Though I truly believe that this search case is very common.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it an option to restructure your data to _embed_ the full activity data, organiser data and translation data in the opportunity data? That is to say, storing the entire data rather than just a referring id?

Comment: Well Organizers and Activities are business entities with a lifecycle of their own. I don't see how the rest of the application would work if I do it this way. May be my former relational-database analysis background blinds me from the NoSQL concepts. So, if I restructure the way you propose, then updating an organizer or activity data would result in thousands of documents writes instead of a single update operation. This looks awkward to me... but may be is it meant to work this way.